# adding up the elements from all of the nested lists

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am  adding up the elements from all of the nested lists, so far what I have is

```
for i in range(len(b)) :
    for j in range(len(b[i])):
        total = total + b[i][j]
```

But this will not work when an integer value exists in the nested list like,

```
b = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], 1]
```

In this case i am getting an error message that object of type 'int' has no len().
what should i do in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sum of nested list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917092/sum-of-nested-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this,
use `sum()` only when the element is an `list` or `tuple`, else simple use the number.

```
>>> b = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], 1]
>>> sum(sum(x) if isinstance(x,(list,tuple)) else x for x in b)
22
```

improving your solution:

```
total=0
b = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], 1]
for i in range(len(b)) :
    if isinstance(b[i],(list,tuple)):
        for j in range(len(b[i])):
            total += b[i][j]
    else:
        total +=b[i]
print total  #prints 22
```

Comment: but it would still fail if there was another layer of lists in one of the sublists (ie `b= [[1,2,[1]],[3,4],[5,6],1]`)

Comment: @JoranBeasley as you can see from OP's approach he's only concerned with list of lists, not list of lists of lists.

Comment: @JoranBeasley That's a different problem. The question did not ask for arbitrarily nested lists and the solution given gives no indication of a need for such.

Comment: yeah I know I was just pointing it out... not saying it was incorrect or anything else( I gave both this and @Lattyware's solution +1)

Comment: Thanks Ashwini, isinstance() solves the problem. I should have remembered it at the very first place.

Comment: @ Joran, Thanks for adding one more level.

Comment: It's worth noting that checking `isinstance()` of the `tuple` and `list` classes is a bad idea as these are not the only iterables, making the solution less likely to work elsewhere. It's not wrong, but it's not as neat a solution, and, as type checking, it's unpythonic (for this reason).

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you are showing a common anti-pattern for Python programmers, don't loop over indices, loop over the objects themselves. E.g:

```
for item in b:
    do_something(item)
```

Rather than:

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    do_something(b[i])
```

It is clearer, simpler and faster.

That said, the main problem you are having is that one of the items isn't a list, so it doesn't have a length.

A better option here is to flatten the list with a generator expression and [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), and then use [the `sum()` builtin function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) to sum the elements.

```
>>> import collections
>>> import itertools
>>> b = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], 1]
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(item if isinstance(item, collections.Iterable) else [item] for item in b))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]
>>> sum(itertools.chain.from_iterable(item if isinstance(item, collections.Iterable) else [item] for item in b))
22
```

We need the generator expression as `itertools.chain()` won't handle non-iterable items, so we place any into a list to work around this.

An alternative would be to make your own generator:

```
def chain_mixed(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        try:
            for subitem in item:
                yield subitem
        except TypeError:
            yield item
```

Then you could simply do:

```
sum(chain_mixed(b))
```

Comment: Nicely done - I'd write it like that except I would use `item if isinstance(item, collections.Iterable) else [item]`

Comment: I am new in Python world so I didn't get half of your code, but Thanks a lot for marking anti pattern used by me and introducing me to generator expression and list comprehension :)

Comment: @JonClements Good idea, changed.

Comment: @Dan If you are new to list comps and generator expressions, I suggest you give [my tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY) a watch.

Comment: @Lattyware : Thanks a lot for the video tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

a generator-based solution

```
>>> b = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], 1]
>>> def sum_up(x):
...     for i in x:
...             if isinstance(i, int):
...                     yield i
...             else:
...                     for j in sum_up(i):
...                             yield j
... 
>>> sum(sum_up(b))
22
>>> b = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6,[3,[6,7]]], 1]
>>> sum(sum_up(b))
38
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it would be

```
def calc_sum(the_list):
    sum = 0
    for item in the_list:
        if isinstance(item,(list,tuple)):
           sum += calc_sum(item)
        else:
           sum += item
    return sum
```

not that pythonic ... but it should work

Answer (score 0):

### Another way to do this

This will work if the list contains nested list and integers/floats
Here I've used python inbuilt function 'sum' to add all the elements of a list

```
def add(nested_list):
    temp=[]
    for i in nested_list:
        if isinstance(i,list):
            temp.append(sum(i))
        else:
            temp.append(i)
    print sum(temp)
```