# sum of nested list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.3

I try to sum a list of nested elements

e.g, `numbers=[1,3,5,6,[7,8]]` should produce `sum=30`

I wrote the following code :

```
def nested_sum(L):
    sum=0
    for i in range(len(L)):
       if (len(L[i])>1):
          sum=sum+nested_sum(L[i])
       else:
          sum=sum+L[i]
    return sum
```

The above code gives following error:

> object of type 'int' has no len()

I also tried `len([L[i]])`, still not working.

Anyone can help? It is Python 3.3

Comment: Try one of the numerous [flatten functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python) posted here so far, and simply `sum(flatten(L))`

Comment: For Python, if I use recursive call, do I need to worry about taking too much time as the stack goes? I know for this problem, I probably won't worry about this

Comment: @Jin It's probably a little early for this, but if you want to reduce memory consumption, use a [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) instead.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to use `isinstance` to check whether an element is a list or not. Also, you might want to iterate over the actual list, to make things simpler.

```
def nested_sum(L):
    total = 0  # don't use `sum` as a variable name
    for i in L:
        if isinstance(i, list):  # checks if `i` is a list
            total += nested_sum(i)
        else:
            total += i
    return total
```

Answer (score 8):

One alternative solution with list comprehension:

```
>>> sum( sum(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in L )
30
```

Edit:
And for lists with more than two levels(thx @Volatility):

```
def nested_sum(L):
    return sum( nested_sum(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in L )
```

Answer (score 7):

It is generally considered more pythonic to [duck type](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-duck-typing), rather than explicit type checking. Something like this will take any iterable, not just lists:

```
def nested_sum(a) :
    total = 0
    for item in a :
        try:
            total += item
        except TypeError:
            total += nested_sum(item)
    return total
```

Answer (score 6):

I would sum the flattened list:

```
def flatten(L):
    '''Flattens nested lists or tuples with non-string items'''
    for item in L:
        try:
            for i in flatten(item):
                yield i
        except TypeError:
            yield item


>>> sum(flatten([1,3,5,6,[7,8]]))
30
```

Comment: Also works with nested tuples and sets.  ```sum(flatten([(1, 2), [3, {4, 5}]]))```.  Excellent!

Answer (score 3):

A quick recursion that uses a lambda to handle the nested lists:

```
rec = lambda x: sum(map(rec, x)) if isinstance(x, list) else x
```

`rec`, applied on a list, will return the sum (recursively), on a value, return the value.

```
result = rec(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

An example using filter and map and recursion:

```
def islist(x): 
    return isinstance(x, list)

def notlist(x): 
    return not isinstance(x, list)

def nested_sum(seq):
    return sum(filter(notlist, seq)) + map(nested_sum, filter(islist, seq))
```

And here is an example using reduce and recursion

```
from functools import reduce


def nested_sum(seq):
    return reduce(lambda a,b: a+(nested_sum(b) if isinstance(b, list) else b), seq)
```

An example using plain old recursion:

```
def nested_sum(seq):
    if isinstance(seq[0], list):
        head = nested_sum(seq[0])
    else:
        head = seq[0]
    return head + nested_sum(seq[1:])
```

An example using simulated recursion:

```
def nested_sum(seq):
    stack = []
    stack.append(seq)
    result = 0
    while stack:
        item = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(item, list):
            for e in item:
                stack.append(e)
        else:
            result += item
    return result
```

Adjustment for handling self-referential lists is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

This code also works.

```
def add_all(t):
    total = 0
    for i in t:
        if type(i) == list: # check whether i is list or not
            total = total + add_all(i)
        else:
            total += i
    return total
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 def sum_nest_lst(lst):
         t=0
         for l in lst:
             if(type(l)==int):
                 t=t+l
             if(type(l)==list):
                 t=t+sum(l)
         print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def nnl(nl): # non nested list function

    nn = []

    for x in nl:
        if type(x) == type(5):
            nn.append(x)

        if type(x) == type([]):
            n = nnl(x)

        for y in n:
            nn.append(y)

     return sum(nn)


 print(nnl([[9, 4, 5], [3, 8,[5]], 6])) # output:[9,4,5,3,8,5,6]

 a = sum(nnl([[9, 4, 5], [3, 8,[5]], 6]))
 print (a) # output: 40
```

Comment: This works fine for any nested list.
To get the expected output you need to go through two phases:
1. Transform the nested list in a normal list
2. Sum up the normal list

Answer (score 0):

**A simple solution would be to use nested loops.**

```
def nested_sum(t):

    sum=0
    for i in t:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            for j in i:
                sum +=j
        else:
            sum += i        
    return sum
```

Comment: Don't use `sum` as a variable name. It shadows the built-in `sum` function.

Answer (score 0):

```py
L = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], 5, [7, 8, 9]]
total = 0 # assign any var 
for a in L: # assign index and start to iterate using if else
    if (isinstance(a, list)): # since its a list you are basically repeating the prev step
        for b in a:
            total += b
    else:
        total += a
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def list_sum(L):
    return sum(list_sum(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in L)
```

Answer (score 0):

at first you should determine the type of the members of the list whether they are list or not before you sum the members .

```
def nested_sum(x):
sum = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
    if type(x[i]) == list:
        sum += nested_sum(x[i])
    else:
        sum+=x[i]
return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up because 'L' is a integer
Perhaps change it to some other data type.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way for solving this problem can be this one-liner:

```
import ast

nested_list = [1,3,5,6,[7,8]]

res = sum(ast.literal_eval(str(nested_list).replace('[','').replace(']','')))

print(res)
```

Disclaimer: I don't think this is an efficient solution, it just works.

Answer (score -1):

```
def nested_sum(lists):
total = 0
for lst in lists:
    s = sum(lst)
    total += s
return total
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing some additional context regarding how and why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Does not answer the original question where list elements can be an `int` or a `list`: "`numbers=[1,3,5,6,[7,8]]`". Cannot apply `sum` on an int.

Answer (score -2):

```py
    #nested sum

    l = [[1, 2], [3,5], [6,2], [4, 5, 6,9]] 

    def nested_sum(lst):

       sum = 0

       for i in lst:
          for j in i:
             sum = sum + j
       
       print(sum)
    
   
nested_sum(l)
```

Comment: Does not answer the original question where list elements can be an `int` or a `list`: "`numbers=[1,3,5,6,[7,8]]`". Also, don't use `sum` as a variable name.

Comment: It works though for me and also for number = [1,3,5,6, [7,8]]

Comment: [No, it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z3Es.png) for `[1,3,5,6, [7,8]]`. Because your inner loop does not work if the list element is a plain int, you cannot iterate over an int.