# Finding the sum of a nested list of ints

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import math
lists =  [1,[2,3],4]
total = 0
for i in range(len(lists)):
    total += sum(i)
print(total)
```

I want it to print,

```
>>>10
```

But throws an error.

I would like it to get it to add all numbers, including the ones within the nested if.

Comment: So, you just want the sum of `2` and `3`?

Comment: What should it print instead?

Comment: Try with reduce http://docs.python.org/release/1.4/tut/node83.html

Comment: You need to flatten the list before adding the values. Iterate through the list and remove any sub-lists, appending their values to the main list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sum of nested list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917092/sum-of-nested-list-in-python)

Comment: This was 8 years ago @Georgy...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your program, `for i in range(len(lists))` - evaluates to 3 as the `lists` object has 3 element. and in the loop `total += sum(i)` it would try to do a `int` + `list` operation, which results in an error. Hence you need to check for the type and then add the individual elements.

```
def list_sum(L):
    total = 0  
    for i in L:
        if isinstance(i, list): 
            total += list_sum(i)
        else:
            total += i
    return total
```

This is @pavelanossov 's comment - does the same thing, in a more elegant way

```
sum(sum(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in L)
```

Comment: `sum(sum(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in L)`

Comment: This is telling me nested_sum is not defined, sorry for missing something, but what should nested sum be? Thanks.

Comment: sorry - typo . just fixed it.

Comment: For me, `sum(sum(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in L)` only works for lists nested at most two levels.  This list fails: `L = ([[1, 1, 1], [1, [1, 1]], 1])`. Not as elegant, but @karthikr function list_sum(L) above works for lists of any level, because of recursion.

Answer (score 6):

You can use flatten function in the compiler.ast module to flatten the list. Then simply sum up all the elements.

```
>>> lists =  [1,[2,3],4]
>>> from compiler.ast import flatten
>>> sum(flatten(lists))
10
```

**EDIT**: Only works with Python 2.x

Comment: this is giving me a error saying no module named 'compiler', how come?

Comment: Actually now I have looked to the documentation, compiler module had been removed in Python 3. I was using Python 2.7

Comment: Has it been replaced by something similar?

Answer (score 0):

numpy.hstack() function is used to stack the sequence of input arrays horizontally (i.e. column wise) to make a single array which is what we require in OP example

```
import numpy as np 

list1 =  [1,[2,3],4]
M = np.hstack(list1) 
print(np.sum(M))
```

gives

```
10

[Program finished]
```