# What would be the non-comprehension list way of doing this sum

Tags: python, sum, list-comprehension, nested-lists

```
def nested_sum(L):
    return sum( nested_sum(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in L )
```

This was a solution given by Eugenie in the following post: [sum of nested list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917092/sum-of-nested-list-in-python)

I just was trying to recreate it without using comprehension list, but I'm not able to get it. How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code uses a [*generator expression*](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), not a list comprehension.

Use a loop and `+=` adding up the results:

```
def nested_sum(L):
    total = 0
    for x in L:
        total += nested_sum(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x
    return total
```

or, if you want the [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) expanded into an `if` statement as well:

```
def nested_sum(L):
    total = 0
    for x in L:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            total += nested_sum(x)
        else:
            total += x
    return total
```

Comment: @ezitoc: Anything missing from the answer that you unaccepted it again? :-)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the "_conditional expression_" keyword. I'm very new to this. And _generator expression_ is new to me as well.

Comment: well at first yes but then I found waht I just commented :)