# Nested sums in Python

Tags: python, loops

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14917111/4089351), but I'm not sure it applies.

I am looking for an easy - minimal calls for packages or special functions - to code in Python what in Maple would be:

```
x:=0:
for m1 from 0 to 9 do
  for m2 from 0 to m1-1 do
    for m3 from 0 to m2-1 do
      for m4 from 0 to m3-1 do
        for m5 from 0 to m4-1 do
          x:=x+1
        od
      od
    od
  od
od:
x;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly with this? Just consume CPU time (which some people do)? Why not do this in a single mathematical operation?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Replicate [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3305046/152225).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
x = 0
for m1 in range(10):
  for m2 in range(m1):
    for m3 in range(m2):
      for m4 in range(m3):
        for m5 in range(m4):
          x = x + 1
```

As you can see, `range()` turns a given number `n` into a list comprised by the numbers `[0, 1, 2, ..., n-1]`.