# Python sum in list consists of integers and other lists and nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum

I have problem with a function that returns a sum of values in list given as argument. But this list can consists of integers and other lists, but this lists can have other lists etc etc
like in example:
[10, 5, [1, [5, 4, 3]], 9, [1, 1, [2, 3]]] => 44

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sum of nested list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917092/sum-of-nested-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten the list and then sum it:

```py
lst = [10, 5, [1, [5, 4, 3]], 9, [1, 1, [2, 3]]]


def flatten(l):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        for v in l:
            yield from flatten(v)
    else:
        yield l


out = sum(flatten(lst))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
44
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also write a recursive function that does the summation:

```
def my_sum(x):
    value = 0
    for i in x:
        if not isinstance(i, list):
           value += i
        else:
           value += my_sum(i)
    return value

my_sum(lst)
44
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a recursive function should work :

```
def your_function(embeded_list):
    n = len(embeded_list)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(n) :
       if len(embeded_list[i]) == 1 :
           sum+=embeded_list[i]
       else :
           sum+=your_function(embeded_list[i])
    return(sum)
```

Comment: please do not use len + range,  iterate on iterables and test using isinstance is much cleaner and readable